# Flutter Vertical Viewport Unbounded Height Error

Tags: dart, flutter

I made an app to display a list of hospitals under a state.

This is the **Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:emas_app/model/accounts_model.dart';

Future<String> _loadAsset() async{
  return await rootBundle.loadString('Assets/accounts.json');
}

Future<Accounts> loadAccounts() async{

  final response = await _loadAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response);

  Accounts accounts = new Accounts.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  return accounts;
}

class ProviderList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  ListState createState() {
    return new ListState();
  }
}

class ListState extends State<ProviderList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget newbody = new ExpansionTile(
        title: new Text("State Name"),
        children: <Widget>[
          new FutureBuilder<Accounts>(
              future: loadAccounts(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if(snapshot.hasData){

                return new ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.accountinfo.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index){

                        String username = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].name;
                        String address = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].street;
                        String lat = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lat;
                        String lng = snapshot.data.accountinfo[index].coordinates.lng;

                        return new ListTile(
                            title: new Text(username),
                            trailing: new Row(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.info),
                                    onPressed: null
                                ),
                                new IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.directions),
                                    onPressed: null
                                )
                              ],
                            )
                        );
                      });
                }else{
                  return new Center(
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              })
    ]);

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Providers")),
      body: newbody
    );
  }
}
```

This is the output where it shows the expanded ExpansionTile is blank:

[image: Providers List]

And this is the error caught:

```
I/flutter ( 6305): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 6305): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 6305): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 6305): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
```

I have tried every possible solution I could find in Stack Overflow by wrapping the ListView.builder with Expanded or Flexible but its not working. Any ideas on how I could go about fixing this issue?

Comment: probablly because you are using a ListView inside a ExptansionTile. Instead of this, you can add another ExpansionTile if you want the child to be expandable or use ListTile to show them like list items.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two solutions:

1. Use **shrinkWrap** property of the ListView

   ```
   new ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: ...
   ```

   **Reason:**

   In your case, `ListView` is inside an `ExpansionTile`. `ExpansionTile` will show expand and show how many ever children are there. ListView will **expand to the maximum size** in scrollDirection as it is placed in ExpansionTile(unbounded constraints widget). As per docs,

   ```
   If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will expand
   to the maximum allowed size in the [scrollDirection]. If the scroll view
   has unbounded constraints in the [scrollDirection], then [shrinkWrap] must
   be true.
   ```
2. Use **SizedBox** for giving fixed height for ListView.

   ```
   SizedBox(height: 200.0, child: new ListView.builder(...))
   ```

Comment: Nothing worked but your solution worked for me! THanks

Comment: What about for a `SliverGrid` instead of a `ListView`? There is no `shrinkWrap` in a `SliverGrid`